# Solving knapsack (0,1) with multiple constraints by dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say I have a collection of objects with weight w and value v. I want to maximize the sum of the value of the selected objects without the sum of their weight going over a maximum W. Until now, classic knapsack problem.

Now suppose each object can belong to category A, B, C, etc... Now I want the objects in my solution to respect the exact number of A, B, C, etc. I'm asking to my algorithm, or else return the nearest solution.

Example :

```
Object 1 : w=4 v=16 Type A
Object 2 : w=3 v=15 Type A
Object 3 : w=2 v=5  Type A
Object 4 : w=1 v=2  Type A
Object 5 : w=1 v=4  Type B
Object 6 : w=2 v=4  Type B
Object 7 : w=2 v=3  Type B
Object 8 : w=4 v=9  Type B
Object 9 : w=3 v=9  Type B
Object 10: w=1 v=2  Type B
Object 11: w=1 v=4  Type B
Object 12: w=4 v=8  Type C
Object 13: w=8 v=19 Type C
Object 14: w=1 v=2  Type C
Object 15: w=3 v=5  Type C

Desired number of objects : A=2 B=5 C=2

Set of objects solution : A{1,2},B{5,6,7,9,11},C{13,15}
```

My first approach was to consider a multidimensionnal array where the first dimension is the number of objects, the 2nd the maximum W, and the others dimension the desired numbers required of each category, and after filling the array with dynamic programming using a weight of 1 if the object belongs to a category and 0 if not. It doesn't work because sometimes some solutions are better with *less* objects.

My second approach was to find each possible subset of the desired number of objects in a category and after using them as instances in a regular dynamic algorithm. It works, but seems inelegant.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your A,B,C seem to be equality constraints , maybe you need to lookup iterative DP.

Answer (score 0):

Just two dimensionnal array is ok.

First, apply an array called `dp[n][m]`, where the first dimension is the number of objects, the second is the sum of `w`. The value of `dp[i][j]` is the maximum of `v` with first `i` object and current weight is `j`.

We can get the equation: `dp[i][j] = max (dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j-w] + v)` where `w` is the weight of `i-th` object and `v` is the value of `i-th` object.

Your answer is `max (dp[n][j] | 0<=j<=W)`

UPD1:

I didn't care about category, you can do this for every category

UPD2:

Sorry I did't see the number of object limit, we can use 3 dimensionnal array instead. Just call `dp[n][k][m]` where `k` is the number of object choosen, `n` and `m` like before.

Equation changes to `dp[i][j][k] = max (dp[i][j][k], dp[i-1][j-1][k-w] + v)`

Answer is `max (dp[n][k][j] | 0<=j<=W)` where `k` is your number limit.

Comment: What you propose is the classic resolution of the problem. I'm already well aware of this one and it doesn't work. In my example, if we do this, we obtain the following solution : A{1,2}B{5,8,9,10,11}C{13} = 78, and the correct solution is A{1,2},B{5,6,7,9,11},C{13,15} = 76. Note how the category C doesn't contain enough objects.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the number limit, I will modify it soon